# How to link rss feed to a url

Tags: ruby, rss, sinatra

I am generating an RSS feed in a Sinatra app, using Ruby's RSS class. The feed will be unique for each user. How do I hook up the feed to a URL so that the user can subscribe with their RSS reader, and automatically receive new feed updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/views/rss_feed_with_builder

Install or add the `Builder` gem:

```ruby
# add to Gemfile and run `bundle`...
gem 'builder'

# ... or install system-wide
$ gem install builder
```

Add appropriate route(s) to your app/controller:

```ruby
# in app.rb
get '/rss' do
  @posts = # ... find posts
  builder :rss
end
```

Create view to show RSS feeds:

```ruby
# in views/rss.builder
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => '1.0'
xml.rss :version => "2.0" do
  xml.channel do
    xml.title "Cool Website News"
    xml.description "The latest news from the coolest website on the net!"
    xml.link "http://my-cool-website-dot.com"

    @posts.each do |post|
      xml.item do
        xml.title post.title
        xml.link "http://my-cool-website-dot.com/posts/#{post.id}"
        xml.description post.body
        xml.pubDate Time.parse(post.created_at.to_s).rfc822()
        xml.guid "http://my-cool-website-dot.com/posts/#{post.id}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Further reading:

- [Sinatra Recipies: RSS Feed with Builder](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/views/rss_feed_with_builder)
- [Sinatra Book: RSS Feeds](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#rss_feed)
- [NetTuts: Singing With Sinatra (RSS)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra-the-encore/)